# Python: How to iterate through a DataFrame into MailMerge fields?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, for-loop, mailmerge, numpy-ndarray

The problem is that each file that is produced using the MailMerge method all have the same merge field data from the first iteration through the i loop, even though the same index conventions called printed through the loop i[0] will display properly as I print each iteration as well as those same index references are used to name each .docx as expected each time through the loop.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from mailmerge import MailMerge
import numpy as np

df1 = xl.parse('Sheet1')
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df1)
data1 = np.array(df2)
template = "Form_Template.docx"
document = MailMerge(template)   



    for i in data1:
        document.merge(
            Name= i[0],
            Domain= 'fruitcorp.local',
            userid= i[1],
            Password= '*',
            date_ini='{:%d-%b-%Y}_______'.format(date.today()),
            comment='* This is a replacement for a missing original form.            
             Original start date was: ',
            startdate= str(i[3]))
         print(i[0])
         document.write(i[1] + 'Replacement_Account_Acceptance_Form.docx')
```

Here is the displayed output that I get:

```
 In: print(data1):
 Out:[['Apple Jacks' 'ajacks' Timestamp('2015-07-26 18:49:11') '26-Jul-015']
 ['Orange Gladys' 'ogladys' Timestamp('2015-01-05 18:50:38')
  '05-Jan-2015']
 ['Ed Banana' 'ebanana' Timestamp('2017-01-09 18:51:47') '09-Jan-2017']
 ['Kiwi Lime' 'klime' Timestamp('2015-02-09 18:52:42') '09-Feb-2015']
 ['Pie Cheesecake' 'pcheesecake' Timestamp('2011-07-28 14:06:26')
  '28-Jul-2011']]

#iterated properly:

In: for i in data1:
         print(i[0])
Out: Apple Jacks
Orange Gladys
Ed Banana
Kiwi Lime
Pie Cheesecake
```

But the same index call to

> i[0]

in the 'Name' field of document.merge function and i[0] similarly for the 'userid' field, results in the iterating value to remain as ['Apple Jacks' 'ajacks' Timestamp('2015-07-26 18:49:11') '26-Jul-2015'] each iteration

```
In: for i in data1:
        document.merge(
           Name= i[0],
           startdate= str(i[3]),
           userid= i[1]))

Out:  Name= Apple Jacks
      startdate= 26-Jul-2015
      userid= ajacks

      Name= Apple Jacks
      startdate= 26-Jul-2015
      userid= ajacks

      Name= Apple Jacks
      startdate= 26-Jul-2015
      userid= ajacks 

      Name= Apple Jacks
      startdate= 26-Jul-2015
      userid= ajacks

      Name= Apple Jacks
      startdate= 26-Jul-2015
      userid= ajacks
```

The same data is repeated each (5) times rather than producing 5 unique sets
All I can think of is that I am not using the DataFrame index properly when I am within the MailMerge method.

> ... Use i[0][0] instead?

```
In: for i in data1:
        document.merge(
           Name= i[0][0],
           startdate= str(i[3][0]),
           userid= i[1][0]))

Out:  Name= A
      startdate= 2
      userid= a

      Name= A
      startdate= 2
      userid= a

      Name= A
      startdate= 2
      userid= a

      Name= A
      startdate= 2
      userid= a

      Name= A
      startdate= 2
      userid= a
```

(Would this be far simpler to access my relational data as a dictionary?) 
The main question is: How can I best get each produced document to contain the correct field data from each iteration of the loop rather than it currently each contains the first row data (all produced documents contain: 'Apple Jacks, ajacks, 26-Jul-2015' in their merge fields)

Comment: This does not feel like it's a minimal example. See [MCVE].

Comment: My apologies for not making this a minimal example. I am new here and also to python, and I thought it would be helpful to show the full methodology in the case where I have gone about this completely wrong

Comment: If I understand correctly, you simply need to index one more time: if `i[0]` is `['Apple Jacks', 'ajacks', Timestamp('2015-07-26 18:49:11'), '26-Jul-2015']`, then `i[0][0]` is  `'Apple Jacks'`.

Comment: Although I think I *don't* understand correctly, there is so much text. Can you simply edit your question to read like this: (1) this is my code, (2) this is my input, (3) this is what I get, (4) this is what I *would like to* get.

Comment: And by "this is what I get" I mean *exactly* what you get copy/pasted, not described in your own words.

Comment: Also you need to show where the `document` variable comes from and what its `merge` method is.

Comment: I updated the code to reflect the use of the MailMerge method from mailmerge as well how the document variable was derived, and added the relevant outputs. Being minimal AND repeatable is requiring more precision than I had anticipated...

Comment: Upon further investigation I believe my issue (or at least ONE of them) is with switching between array indexing and DataFrame index. Additionally it looks like my array or arrays set didn't get populated as I intended. I may go back to the DataFrame method

Answer (score 1):

I found that the issue was with the use of the MailMerge method before the loop. It is necessary to initialize the document variable each iteration (therefore INSIDE) the loop:

```
from mailmerge import MailMerge
import pandas as pd

df3 = pd.DataFrame(df1, index = range(int(len(df2.index))))
looprange = range(int(len(df3.index)))

for j in looprange:
#The following line was previously before the loop. It MUST be here: 
    document = MailMerge(template)
    document.merge(
        Name= df3.name[j],
        Domain= 'fruitcorp.local',
        userid= df3.SamAccountName[j],
        Password= '*',
        date_ini='{:%d-%b-%Y}_______'.format(date.today()),
        comment='* This is a replacement for a missing original form. 
        Original start date was: ',
        startdate= df3.WhenCreatedFormated[j])
    document.write(df3.SamAccountName[j] + '_Replacement_Account_Acceptance_Form.docx')
```